# How to increment counter in before return without passing a callback function?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using angular and I can't get my counter to work.
I have this function:

```
$scope.statClass = function(summoner, key) {
  var stat = 'stat-same';
  if(shouldRevert(key)) {
    summoner === 1 ? summoner = 2 : summoner = 1;
  }
  if(summoner === 1) {
    if($scope.champData1[key] > $scope.champData2[key]) {
      $scope.score1++;
      stat = 'stat-bigger';
    } else if ($scope.champData1[key] < $scope.champData2[key]) {
      stat = 'stat-lower';
    }
  } else if(summoner === 2) {
    if($scope.champData2[key] > $scope.champData1[key]) {
      $scope.score2++;
      stat = 'stat-bigger';
    } else if ($scope.champData2[key] < $scope.champData1[key]) {
      stat = 'stat-lower';
    }
  }
  return stat;
};
```

Which runs when I'm trying to determine the class to format a certain 'div' block.
Everytime my pages load and the {{score1}} or {{score2}} is displayed, it is displayed as 'null'.
How can I increment my score values before returning the stat?

PS.: I have declared $scope.score1 and 2 outside the function.

Comment: I don't think it's immediately obvious from this snippet why your counter isn't working.  Did you initialize `score1` and `score2` to `0`?

Comment: It might be a scope issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A new instance of the controller is created every time an element tied to that controller enters the DOM. Each instance of the controller has unique counters.

If by "Everytime my pages load":

1. You mean that the browser is refreshing the entire page, don't do that, :-), angular is for 'Single Page Application's. No data is carried over from one load to the next.
2. You mean that a new route is loaded, this is expected. Use a service and/or $broadcast/$emit+$on to keep the counters in sync
3. The DOM element becomes visible through ng-if or ng-switch: These cause the element to be taken out an re-inserted to the DOM creating a new controller (if the controller is in/under the ng-if'd element). Use ng-show/ng-hide instead. These change the display properties, but keep the elements in the DOM.